# Bootstrap 3 and Tabs : How set custom color for more than one active tab?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get my active tabs to show the color of its background rather than the default white. I could easily do this if I was just using one set of nav tabs, but I need to figure out how to do it with more than one set (as shown in my demo). [Demo here](http://ogmda.com/test/tabs.php)
Here's my HTML (CSS below as well as a link to demo)

```
<div class="row nav-set1">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
<p>Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here   and there again and again.</p>  
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
<p>Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here and there again and again. Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here and there again and again. Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here and there again and again.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!--/.row-->
<br/><br/>

<div class="row nav-set2">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#home2" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#profile2" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home2">
<p>Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here   and there again and again.</p>  
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile2">
<p>Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here and there again and again. Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here and there again and again. Some text can go here and there and here and there again. Yes, some text will g here and there again and again.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!--/.row-->
```

CSS code:

```
.nav-set1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the current markup:

```
.nav-set1 .nav .active a {
    background-color: grey ;
}

.nav-set2 .nav .active a {
    background-color: blue ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: red; /* or any color that you want as the font color*/
    cursor: default;
}